# How to override Java's ArrayList's addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) method in Scala? Naive approach does not compile

Tags: java, scala, collections, arraylist, overriding

In [MyList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBL2Z.png) I try to override `ArrayList`'s `addAll` method (Fig. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDaxY.png)). 
But it does not compile (Fig. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rNCe.png)).

How can this be fixed ?

Why is the type incompatible ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

Here is `MyList` as text:

```
import java.util
import java.util.ArrayList

class MyList[T] extends ArrayList[T]{
  override def toString()="MyList"

  override def add(o:T)= {
    println ("adding "+o)
    super.add(o)
  }

  override def addAll(c: util.Collection[_ <: T])
  {
    println("addAll"+c)
    super.addAll(c)
  }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331085/how-to-override-javas-arraylists-addallcollection-extends-e-c-method-in-s/https://biblereasons.com/oceans/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth/https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Methamphetamine#section=DEA-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a `=`. It should be:

```
override def addAll(c: util.Collection[_ <: T])= {
    println("addAll"+c)
    super.addAll(c)
}
```

Comment: @jhegedus You're welcome :) It happens also to me sometimes, pulling my hair to see what's wrong with my code but it was just that!